# Gradle showing errors of dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-design-library

When I changed constraint layout version to alpha-2 it showing error. previously I was using an older version it was not showing any error:

**older version workes fine without error:**

```
dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha2' 
}
```

**new version with error:**

```
dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha2' 
}
```

gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 28
  defaultConfig {
     applicationId "com.m3tech.transitionspractice"
     minSdkVersion 21
     targetSdkVersion 28
     versionCode 1
     versionName "1.0"
     testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
  buildTypes {
      release {
        minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
  } 
}

dependencies {
     implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
     implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
     implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha2' 
 }
```

**error:**

[image]

Comment: post your all gradle or dependencies which you are using.

Comment: You just posted same snippet twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha2'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this code to fix that. Put in your app module `build.gradle`:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion "28.0.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```